# How to have fixed size checkbox column in nz-table while using nz-resizable directive

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I really need to use the resizable component in the tables of my app, so columns can be redimensionable. I know it's on experimental state, but I need it and its working fine, mostly. Also need to have a first column with checkboxes for selection purposes. I expected the checkbox column to remain fixed size. What is happening is the checkbox column changes width when I resize the other columns.

Here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqs53u?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty little trick solved it. Added a dummy column at the end that gets resized instead, and bind the width of checkbox column to a variable. The link in the post shows the final state.